# How to add a list of literals to an SQL result

Tags: mysql, sql-server, literals

As part of a larger SQL query I want to add some literal values to a sub-query result. Is there a neater way of doing it than this?

```
..blah blah.. where ORDER_NUMBER in
(
select ORDER_NUMBER from PAYMENT where PAYMENT_STATUS = 1
union select 200
union select 452
union select 123
);
```

There might be a long list of values, so I would something like `where x in (200,452,123)` instead of repeating "union select" for each value.

Comment: just use `OR ORDER_NUMBER in (200,452,123)` in your query.

Answer (score 0):

```
...
where ORDER_NUMBER in (select ORDER_NUMBER from PAYMENT where PAYMENT_STATUS = 1) 
   or ORDER_NUMBER in (200,452,123,...);
```

or

```
...
where ORDER_NUMBER in (
   select ORDER_NUMBER from PAYMENT where PAYMENT_STATUS = 1
   union select a from (VALUES (200),(452),(123)) as b(a)
);
```

Comment: I was trying to find a way of adding it to the subquery, but your solution is also fine. Thanks (also to mitkosoft)

Comment: @user3302618, I added variant with subquery to the answer